# I want my action to alter the DOM element it is attached to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ember.js, handlebars.js

By alter I mean changing color/font size/ etc.

So this is the action in my controller

```
actions {
  changeColor: function() {
    this.$().css('background-color', '#f1f1f2'); //error!
  }
}

 <span  {{action 'changeColor' this}} > </span>
```

`this.$()` is causing an error. What should I use instead?

The action must be in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `{{action 'someAction' this}}` `this` from within the `template` in this sense will refer to the model/content of the template not the DOM element of the action.

Here is another suggestion. I am not sure if this is best practice.

Lets say we are working within the index template and have a span with a action:

```
 //index template

 <span>Change my background</span>
```

Now the index template has a `view` that is backing it called the IndexView. Within that View we can use one of the DOM events. in the code below we use the `click` Dom event which will send along an event with which we can use to the grab the target and then send to controller.

```
 //App.IndexView

   click: function(evt) {
      //get the evt target
      var target = evt.target
      //send a action the controller
      this.get('controller').send('handleBackgroundChange', target);    
 }
```

Now in the indexController:

```
 //indexController

 actions:  { 
    handleBackgroundChange: function(target) {
      $(target).css({'background': 'green'});
    }    
 }
```

Again this works but I am not sure it is a good idea.

Comment: This is great, however 'click' function we added in the IndexView is making everything that I click turn to green. I only want the object that is clicked to turn green

Comment: Update: I simply made my own view for the item i wished to be clicked and that solved the issue & then I added bubbles=false to the view on the html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do that change with jQuery, you can do something like the following:

```
// You'd have to know the selector of that view or the css class wrapping it
// in order to do this in the controller, since the "this" 
// is not a pointer to your view at this point (I think)
Ember.$('selector goes here selector').css({'color': '#00F'});
```

It would be much easier form a view instead of a controller, since you could do things like (note the `this` keyword):

```
this.$().css('color': '#0F0');
```

This code would work in a view with the `this` keyword and without the need for a selector, since it is a pointer to the `view` at that moment. So `this.$()` in a view would essentially mean `$("#ember416")` where "ember416" is the `id` Ember assigned to that view.

Another way you can do this would be through a `View` or `Component` implementation so you could use `attributeBindings` for `style`, and have a lot more control over what is going on. You can apply rules to specific css properties based on the business reqs and take advantage of the binding to always recompute the style. With this approach you don't need to use `$.css()` to change the styles, as it gets built and applied for you.

So... say you create a `style` property watches other properties (e.g. color, border, size, etc) within your class and ultimately compose the style string. This way you can `program` each property and then bind the result of a given combination directly to your view via `attributeBindings`. Example:

```
// JS
App = Em.Application.create();

App.LeToggleButtonComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  
  // I want an input
  tagName: 'input', 
 
  // of the type button
  type: 'button',
    
  // that has a `clicked` flag
  clicked: false,
    
  // When I change the `clicked` flag, I want my to force any
  // properties depending on `clicked` to re-evaluate their values
  changeColor: function() { 
     this.toggleProperty('clicked');
  }.on('click'),
  
  // Then I want the color attribute to re-evaluate itself
  // based on the `clicked` property, switching it from red to blue
  color: function() {
    return "color: %@;".fmt((this.get('clicked')) ? "#00F" : "#F00");
  }.property('clicked'),
  
  // And I also want the border attribute to re-evaluate itself
  // based on the `clicked` property, switching it from red to blue
  border: function() {
    return "border: %@;".fmt((this.get('clicked')) ? "1px solid #00F" : "1px solid #F00");
  }.property('clicked'),
  
  // Then I want to combine all css related properties
  // into a single string, composing the style of this component
  style: function() {
    return '%@1%@2'.fmt(this.get('border'), this.get('color'));    
  }.property('border', 'color')
  
  // finally, I want to bind some attributes to the view
  // so the styles get updated automatically when 
  // any of them change. The real important one, is the `style` prop
  attributeBindings: ['type', 'value', 'style'],
  
});

// Handlebars
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='index'>
    {{le-toggle-button value='Click Here'}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='application'>
    <h2>button test</h2>
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

(see [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/quwepihuniqo/1/edit))

An argument can be made (and I'd agree) that for the majority of the scenarios, one should use classes instead of inline styles. This proposed approach would be good when you have very specific rules and/or complex style combinations that could potentially create duplicated/hard-to-maintain css classes.

## Update

I wanted to satisfy my own curiosity on how to send and handle css changes through a controller or route and went on reading. I came up with a second solution that allows for changes made directly in the controller or route:

```
// JS
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() { 
  this.route('other');
});

App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    changeColor: function(selector) { 
      console.log("Index > Ember.$('%@')".fmt(selector), Ember.$(selector));
      
      // now I can simply call jQuery to 
      // change the style of the view in 
      // this particular route
      Ember.$(selector).css({
        'color': '#F00',
        'font-weight': 'bold'
      });
      
    }
  }
});

App.OtherRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    changeColor: function(selector) { 
      
      console.log("Other > Ember.$('%@')".fmt(selector), Ember.$(selector));
     
      // or on this one
      Ember.$(selector).css({
        'height': '80px'
      });
    }
  }
});

App.LeOtherButtonComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
 
  tagName: 'input',  
  type: 'button',
  target: Ember.computed.alias('route'), 
  
  // within the action handler, you can 
  // call this.triggerAction, passing the 
  // action name, context and target.
  // in this case, i didn't pass the target
  // with the hash, but left as the default 
  // target of the view, and also changed
  // it's default value to the route just
  // as an example
  changeColor: function(e) { 
    
    var selector = '#%@'.fmt(this.get('elementId'));
    
    this.triggerAction({
      action: 'changeColor', 
      actionContext: selector
    });
    
  }.on('click'), 
   
  attributeBindings: ['type', 'value' ] 

});

// Markup
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='index'>
    {{le-other-button value='Click Here - Index'}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='other'>
    {{le-other-button value='Click Here - Other'}}
</script>
  
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='application'>
    <div class="more">
        {{#link-to 'index'}}Index{{/link-to}} | 
        {{#link-to 'other'}}Other{{/link-to}}
    </div>
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

(see [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/niqevujevela/1/edit))

I don't really know if I like this solution because it's really easy to go out of sync with inline styles versus whatever state your view/component is supposed to be in and look like at that point. The approach on the first hypothetical component is good because you can tell exactly what is going to change, without the need of using jQuery. On the other hand, you have to create a computed property and add it as a dependency of the style each time you want to add a new style attribute in that string, making the 2nd hypothetical component look more flexible, allowing each controller/route to implement its own `changeColor`, and allowing you to inject an animation or another type of operation in that component or view.  But I think it sorta leaves it open for imperative style changes (not tied to any logic/rule, which can become difficult to maintain).

I'm sure there's a better way to do this :P

Comment: I think 'this' in the controller at that time is reference to the controller and not the view. But $() gives you the view, that is why you can add selector and whatever other jquery stuff.

Comment: Yeah, that's right about `this`. Also, (and I haven't tried this or read much more yet, but I suspect that) if he accept an argument on `changeColor` action handler, it could actually be the reference to the view as per his `<span  {{action 'changeColor' this}} > </span>` definition... right?

Comment: Interesting enough `this` within a template seems to the model/context and not the element that you want. So passing `this` as a parameter in the action will pass the context. lol

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to bind the DOM node's `class` attribute to a controller property, like this:

```
<div {{bind-attr 'class' myClass}}>blah blah</div>
```

and in your action:

```
actions: {
    changeColor: function() {
        this.set('myClass', 'someCssClass');
    }
}
```

If you'd rather deal with styles directly (not recommended), then you could do the same thing with the `style` attribute binding.

Comment: But is there another version of `this.$()` that will select itself, depending on what DOM element `{{action 'changeColor' this}}` is attached to?

Comment: You could create a custom `View`, or create a `Mixin` that can configure the DOM node upon insertion (use `on('didInsertElement')`).  Attach a click listener and handle it that way.

Comment: I tried the recommended approach and i received the error Object.keys called on non-object